# PHP: Track Quantity & Total Price from Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

looked through forums before posting.

I have a unique PHP setup where i'd like to track quantity and total price of items in a cart. Only issue is i can't get it to work.

This is my first time actually making some from scratch in PHP.

Here's how my setup works.

First off i am using a global variable to parse and call certain items from the database.

On certain form submissions certain items come back.

For this issue in particular i am passing a value, the item ID, through a link which references to another file that processes the request.

This file creates a session array that the cart pulls and references ITEM ID's to the MYSQL database. It is called  $_SESSION['cart'].

Here's what i wrote for the code;

```html
// PASS ITEM ID TO ADD CART PAGE. WHERE pID = Product ID.

<?php

 // Pull information from DB to translate into HTML
     
 $results->data_seek(0);

 while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

  $pId = $row['ProductID'];
    }

?>

<a href="addc.php?id=<?php echo $pId ?>"> Add to cart </a>


// ADD ITEMS TO CART


// Session
session_start();


// If empty cart set empty 

if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array ();
}


// Store ID 

$thisID = $_GET['id'];


// Push ID into Array

array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$thisID); // ADDS TO ARRAY

header('Location:cart.php'); // REDIRECTS TO CART


// NOW ON CART PAGE

// Convert Cart Session to Strings & Store

if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array ();
 $itemId  = 0;
} else {
 $itemId  = implode(",",$_SESSION['cart']);
}


// Reference Above Strings to DB

$results = run_my_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN ($itemId)");
```

Now the issues with this

- Allows multiple entries, but the product is only displayed once (Thus i want to track quantity)
- No sure way of totaling products based off of items pulled

After this point i tried making the array an associative array and merging the two arrays together, but i think there's an easier way to do this, just don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the quantity of each item in the cart at the time you push the IDs of the items in the array?

Comment: Not in this working version. I tried making the array act like this after i posted; "ID" => $itemID, "QT" => $itemQT. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the product ID as the key in your cart array, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$thisID] = $quantity;
```

It's FAR easier to look up a particular item in the cart this way, without having to loop on the array or use `in_array()`.

---

as per comment request, here's how you'd handle some basic cart operations:

Add to cart, or update quantity in cart:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$productID] = $_POST['item_quantity'];
```

Remove from cart:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$productID]);
```

Get IDs of products in cart:

```
$product_IDs_array = array_keys($_SESSION['cart']);
```

See if an item is in the cart, and how many of it:

```
$amount = isset($_SESSION['cart'][$productID]) ? false : $_SESSION['cart'][$productID];
```

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate? I understand the concept, but not the application.